# Так и должно быть?

Tags: javascript, html, json

При получении JSON данных из php, JSON попадает в html [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

php `$arr = array('title' => 'Тайтел', 'text' => 'Hello'); echo json_encode($arr);`

JavaScript `data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data.text;`

Скажите так и должно быть ?

Comment: а что ты ожидаешь от юникода?

Comment: Забацай вот так: json_encode( $text, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );

Comment: Я не про \u0422 и т д ! Я про весь массив что он попадает в в конец HTML

Comment: ну из твоего вопроса `Так и должно быть?` и кучи стрелок довольно таки сложно вычленить, что ты не про \u0422

Comment: А куда ты ождаешь что попадет ответ? судя по представленному коду он вообще у тебя не должен был сработать ибо элемента `#content` у тебя нет

Comment: `#content` точно есть и туда выводятся данные из этого массива !

Comment: Значит что-то не так с картинкой, ибо на ней нет `#content`

Comment: `#content точно есть` - в вопросе ничего нет. пример не воспроизводится. давай полный код html, js и Php

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы ! Разобрался в чем проблема ! Проблема была с навигацией получается php грузился 2 раза!